# Text in my image file doesn't display properly in final render

Tags: rendering

This happens to all the words.  Everything looks fine until I hit render.  I tried making a new material and plugging the image texture into the diffuse, nothing changed.  Not sure where to look to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Looks like Z-fighting. Meshes are overlapping.

Comment: Damn, that makes sense.  I think that is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! The model came from an AutoCAD software, not sure what happened but it looks like it duplicated the geometry and made it as one piece.  Hard to notice in the viewport. In the UV editor, I was able to isolate the appropriate faces and delete them. Thank you LukeD for the speedy response.